# Unable to download npm scoped artifacts

Tags: npm, artifactory

After an upgrade to 5.1.3 our npm repo does not allow to download npm scoped artefacts.

```
npm install @angular/core
npm ERR! Linux 3.10.0-514.2.2.el7.x86_64
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/node" "/bin/npm" "install" "@angular/core"
npm ERR! node v6.9.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.8
npm ERR! code E401

npm ERR! Registry returned 401 for GET on https://artifactory.mycompany.com/artifactory/api/npm/npmrepo/@angular%2fcore
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /root/npm-debug.log
```

We have a apache reverse proxy in front of artifactory with:

- AllowEncodedSlashes On
- AllowEncodedSlashes NoDecode

and on tomcat:

```
-Dorg.apache.tomcat.util.buf.UDecoder.ALLOW_ENCODED_SLASH=true
```

I even tried downloading with apache turned off. Results were the same. Because of something unkown to me tomcat is decoding slash.

```
@angular%2fcore
```

Comment: Just to make sure, you defined in your '.npmrc' file the use of scoped packages, as written in the Artifactory NPM documentation:

For example:
@angular:registry=http://localhost:8081/artifactory/api/npm/npm-virtual/

Comment: And another thing to check, as you got 401, check the permissions for the user that run the command. 401, means that the user doesn't have sufficient permissions. You should also look in the request.log in Artifactory to see what user is listed for that request in Artifactory.

Comment: Hi A part of my .npmrc file @angular:registry=https://artifactory.mycompany.com/artifactory/api/npm/npmtestext I guess I'm getting 401 because of %2f in URL. There is no repo or artifact @angular%2fcore. PS for testing purposes I created an account with full privileges to every npm repo and now I'm using it.

Comment: Hi, 
The scope is added after the repository key when using npm install 'http://localhost:12002/artifactory/api/npm/npm/@angular%2fcore'.

One thing I noticed but not sure is related is that you should end the registry url with a '/'
e.g. here is my example of using scope with npm repository called 'npm'
@angular:registry=http://localhost:12002/artifactory/api/npm/npm/

If you can add the outcome of your install request with the verbose flag using 'npm i @angular/core --verbose' might be able to help a bit more.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I solved it by adding the following in my `.npmrc`:

```
always-auth = false
```

But our artifactory server is in HTTP.